# How to convert a Bitmap to ByteArray without the use of compression?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I would like to convert an instance of `Bitmap`to an instance of `ByteArray`in order to be able to pass it to a Webservice.

Right now, what I'm doing is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);  
byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(imageData, imagePath);
```

The problem here, is that I am using compression to make it happen, and this results in lowering the quality of the bitmap.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
I can't compress to `PNG`, since the server uses `JPEG`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **As Sean Owen said, use png rather than jpeg.**
- You can get an *int* array with `getPixels()`.
- You can get a buffer object with `copyPixelsToBuffer()`, which you
  can later convert to a byte[].

In any case png compression is the best solution as it does not need as many intermediary operations and gives a compressed result.

Comment: But #2 and #3 give you raw ARGB pixels, and are certainly not the encoding of an image in JPEG format. You say you must have JPEG.

Comment: Well, to be fair the original question only regarded "convert an instance of Bitmap to an instance of ByteArray". The best solution is still to do what he already does but with png, as you already answered. As far as I know the android jpeg compression is quite bad even at 100% quality.

Comment: @Jave I agree, this is what I would do too except for the JPEG requirement. I don't know about the quality but I suppose he could try other JPEG encoders.

Comment: Hmm. Do you know if the JPEG compression is better on iOS?

Answer (score 3):

Use a lossless format like PNG then. JPEG is lossy.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentionned that I really need to keep the JPEG format, because this is the format used by the server.

Comment: Then you are doing all you can by requesting maximum quality from the JPEG encoder. If you must send JPEG, then by definition you are losing some information -- but with max quality JPEG loses very little.